# ImageButton state don't reset to Normal

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visualstatemanager

Faced such a problem, if you use `ImageButton` together with `VisualStateManager` and click on it, and then slide your finger outside of the control and release, then the state is not reset to Normal.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Here's an example of the ImageButton style:

```
<Style x:Key="ProductButton" TargetType="ImageButton">
<Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="70"/>
<Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="210"/>
<Setter Property="Aspect" Value="Fill"/>
<Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
<Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
    <VisualStateGroupList>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateGroupList>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Also please provide a [mre].

Comment: @APXANGEL I test your code on Android platform, it works fine, but having problem on Uwp and ios, I find there is one thread to report this problem at github:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10859

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, I was aware that the developers knew about this problem, but I thought maybe the community has some ways to work around this behavior. Perhaps custom renderers or replacement of the visualStateManager itself. There is a method VisualStateManager.GoToState (Element, "Normal") that returns to normal, but where to call it?

Comment: @APXANGEL I want to put `VisualStateManager.GoToState((ImageButton)sender, "Normal");` in ImageButton_Released or ImageButton_Unfocused, but these events are not be fired when you unpress outside of imagebutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find one workround that using platform effect that triggers the released event when the touch up occurs outside the Imagebutton.

Create effect in the .NET Standard library(shared code).

```
public class SpecialButtonEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public SpecialButtonEffect() : base($"MyCompany.{nameof(SpecialButtonEffect)}")
    {
    }
}
```

Implementing SpecialButtonEffect in ios:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(EffectTest.iOS.Effects.SpecialButtonEffect), 
nameof(EffectTest.iOS.Effects.SpecialButtonEffect))]
namespace EffectTest.iOS.Effects
{
public class SpecialButtonEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        (Control as UIButton).TouchUpOutside += OnTouchUpOutside;
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        (Control as UIButton).TouchUpOutside -= OnTouchUpOutside;
    }

    private void OnTouchUpOutside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (Element as IButtonController).SendReleased();
    }
}
}
```

consuming the effect in xaml.

```
<ImageButton
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
           
            Source="favorite.png"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ImageButton.Effects>
                <local:SpecialButtonEffect  />
            </ImageButton.Effects>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale" Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale" Value="0.5" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </ImageButton>
```

Comment: @APXANGEL I test code on Android 9.0, it works fine, no problem. You have same problem on Android?

Comment: @APXANGEL If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, it is beneficial to others.

Comment: Thank you, this solved half of the problem, but the question remains open with working on android.

Comment: This is strange, I tested in the android 9 emulator and on a real android 10 device, it is reproduced everywhere.